# Problem with custom module

Tags: magento2

I have a problem with an ajax call.
In my site I have 2 types of clients configured, with one client working correctly and with the other type of client the call returns me `<doctype html> <html><head></head><body></body></html>`, in summary it returns html code.

I have a controller that receives the ajax call and the only thing I'm doing in the execute function is `echo 'hello';`, it only works on the first type of client.

The code of Controller is this:
[image]

This is the ajax call:
[image]

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Show your controller code. No one could help you without code review.

Comment: I edit the post with controller and ajax call